# php56w-common conflicts with older version of php (Centos)

Tags: centos, php, installation, yum, vagrant

I am trying to update my vagrant box to use PHP 5.6, and I am basically doing the following process on the command line.

- sudo yum remove php* (remove PHP)
- wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm (Installs the latest remi repo:)
  rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm
- sudo yum install php php-common php-devel php-fpm php-gd php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-mysqlnd php-pdo php-pear php-soap php-xml php-pecl-apcu php-pecl-xdebug php-pecl-amqp

The first two steps seem fine however on the final step when doing the 'setup install process' I get the following error :

```
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I need all of the modules above compatible with PHP 5.6, can anyone suggest what I should do next to get this working?

Answer (score 8):

You should do

`sudo yum install php56w php56w-common` ...

instead of

`sudo yum install php php-common`, ...

Comment: `yum list available 'php56w-*'` and look for the package(s) you want. The architecture extension (eg. .x86_64) is not necessary for the `yum install` command.

Answer (score 5):

Using remi repository, you need to enable the repository matching the wanted version, so for 5.6:

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56
```

Then use the usual yum command.

Comment: He also should disable the webtatic repository, lest some of those conflicting packages get installed.

Comment: @Remi thanks your repo site is brilliant! thanks for taking the time to answer this question :-)

Comment: Note: The above doesn't automatically enable the basic remi repository, which is necessary to install some dependencies for the GD library. One should enable the remi repo as well.

Comment: @Ynhockey all the dependencies are in the "remi-safe" repository, which is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Cheers guys - I had already found a solution before I read your posts, so used the method from this site

https://www.mojowill.com/geek/howto-install-php-5-4-5-5-or-5-6-on-centos-6-and-centos-7/

In a nutshell I did the following:

**CentOS 6 installation**

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm
```

**Enable the repo**
Modify the /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo file

```
[remi]
name=Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/mirror
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
```

Then in the same file there is a section for php56 and I set the enabled flag from 0 to 1 and voila! Next time I ran the yumo install command it all went through without any errors.

e.g

```
sudo yum install php php-gd php-mysql php-mcrypt
```

Comment: Notice that enabling "remi" is not more required, all dependencies are in base, epel and remi-safe (which is enabled by default)